# Cannot verify facebook messenger webhook, curl_errno = 28

Tags: facebook, validation, curl, webhooks, ngrok

i want to configure webhook for facebook application.during the development process i was using ngrock, which was working perfectly, today i cann't establish connection. Address is
https://.........ngrok.io , which works and returns ok
i try to add webhook https://.......ngrok.io/webhook to the facebook application , getting error like this

The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 28; curl_error = Operation timed out after 6001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received; HTTP Message = Unknown Response Code

Can you help, what can i do?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/824028317765435/

Answer (score 0):

I've spend 2 hours to fix it. And final, I find it is a bug :)
Facebook fixed it.