# Why does my Facebook Webhook Subscription Verification timeout on my ngrok URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, ngrok

I've been using ngrok for several weeks while building the first version of my Web Server so that I can send it test Webhooks from a Facebook App.

Until today, I could always just update my Webhooks subscriptions with the new auto-generated ngrok URL just fine.  But today, when I try to verify my ngrok URL with my Facebook App's Webhooks, I do NOT get an indication from my server that it ever received a GET request, I keep getting the timeout message:

> The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the
>   following errors: curl_errno = 28; curl_error = Operation timed out
>   after 6001 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received; HTTP Message =
>   Unknown Response Code

However, when I use Postman to hit the same ngrok URL, everything works fine - I can see that I'm getting back the challenge string and my server indicates that it received the GET request and responded with a 200 code.  I haven't changed the logic of the verification endpoint in my server since I last used the Facebook Webhooks (yesterday).

---

Graph API version is 2.9.  I made sure I was using the HTTPS URL ngrok provides, as I have been doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44678627/1427878

Comment: So future people don't have to follow the SO link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/824028317765435/

Summary: This is a known bug and Facebook is working on it.